# How to create a two barplots for two subjects, with multiple columns on the x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, bar-chart

I need to create bar graphs for two types of animals for different columns on the x-axis.

To make it more clear

My data is something like that:

```
ID, Type, Baseline_Respiratory_Rate (BLRR), Day3_RR, Day7_RR, Day14_RR
1 Stroke   233
2 Stroke  200
3 Sham   250
4 Sham   450
5 Sham   350
6 Stroke  234
7 Stroke   180
8 Sham    300
9 Sham    250
10 Stroke  166
```

So I need to plot the average Respiratory rates on different days on the x-axis, (Baseline, Day3, Day7, Day4), and each day has two bars, one for stroke and one for sham, all on the same plot.

I can't figure a way to do it as a beginner, I'm trying to learn R systematically but I need to learn this now.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your data is not complete I guess. There a no values for Day3_Rr, Day7_RR....

Answer (score 1):

In your data the values for day 3 onwards are missing. So I will use the following smaller dataset for illustration.

```
ID;Type;baseline;day1
1;Stroke;233;133
2;Stroke;200;100
3;Sham;250;200
4;Sham;450;300
5;Sham;350;200
6;Stroke;234;230
7;Stroke;180;190
8;Sham;300;290
9;Sham;250;150
10;Stroke;166;200
```

Put this in a dataframe called "animals". Now

```
tmp<-aggregate(animals[,3:4],list(type=animals$Type),mean)
```

gives the average respiratory for each day and type. To get a barplot use

```
barplot(as.matrix(tmp[2:3]),beside=TRUE)
```

You can make the barplot a bit nicer by adding a legend, labels for the axes and so on... I leave that to you.

Comment: This is really helpful and the most straightforward, but can you help me with how to do it with ggplot? because I'd like to add error bars or more things to my plots, and ggplot is easier for me than base R

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical workflow process option using "Tidyverse" - there are other ways to achieve this..

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(id, type)) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("blrr", "day3_rr", "day7_rr", "day14_rr"))) %>% 
  group_by(name, type) %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(name, avg, fill = type))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())

**data**

#to make the outcome repeatable
set.seed(123)

#representative dataset
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10,
                 type = sample(c("Stroke", "Sham"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                 blrr = runif(10, 150, 450),
                 day3_rr = runif(10, 150, 450),
                 day7_rr = runif(10, 150, 450),
                 day14_rr = runif(10, 150, 450))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete solution with fake data:

```
library(tidyverse)

# add fake data for Day 3, 7, 14 
set.seed(123)
Day3_RR <- sample(166:450,10)
Day7_RR <- sample(166:450,10)
Day14_RR <- sample(166:450,10)
BLRR <- c(233, 200, 250, 450, 350, 234, 180, 300, 250, 166)
Type <- c("Stroke", "Stroke", "Sham", "Sham", "Sham", "Stroke", "Stroke", "Sham", "Sham", "Stroke") 
ID <- 1:10
df <- cbind(ID, Type, BLRR, Day3_RR, Day7_RR, Day14_RR)

# tweak dataframe, to longformat with `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` package
df <- df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = T) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols= c(starts_with("Day"), BLRR), 
    names_to = "time",
    values_to = "RR"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(time = factor(time, levels = c("BLRR", "Day3_RR", "Day7_RR", "Day14_RR"))) %>% 
  group_by(Type, time) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(avg_RR = mean(RR, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup()


ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=avg_RR, fill = Type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=round(avg_RR)), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly fine, with only one problem.

Some of my animals die on day3 and day7, so their data is NA for that column, when I did that it only gave me columns for BL_RR and the others had no columns. I tried using na.omit() for these columns but with no success as I'm not sure where it goes into the code.

Thanks a lot, absolutely grateful.

Comment: add `mutate(RR = if_else(is.na(RR), 0, RR))` after `pivot_longer()`